# How to pass state params to $location.url in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my Angular JS app , I pass some parameters in the URL on a state change

```
    $state.go('dashboard.checkoutsuccess', { hostedid: hostedPageId, appName:$scope.appName});
```

However I want to use $location.url() to do the state change but how does one pass the above params to this?

```
     $location.url( "/dashboard/checkoutsuccess" );
     $location.replace();
```

Answer (score 4):

Angular's `$location` service's `search()` method, provides a getter and setter for query string parameters.

`$location.search()` **without arguments** is a **getter**, which returns an object containing all the query string parameters. `$location.search()` **with arguments** is a **setter**, which will write to the query string.

**Setter :**

```
$location.path('/new').search({foo: 'bar', baz:'xoxo'})
```

will change the URL to ;

```
`http://example.com/#/new?foo=bar&baz=xoxo`
```

**Getter :**

Given url `http://example.com/#/new?foo=bar&baz=xoxo`

```
var searchObject = $location.search();
```

Will return

```
{foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}
```